# Does the determinant of an $n\times n$ matrix of this form always equal the $(n-2)$th superfactorial?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, determinant, factorial

I was reading [the wikipedia page on the Toom-Cook algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication), and I found it strange that there are [several interpolation matrices given for various $k$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toom%E2%80%93Cook_multiplication#Interpolation_matrices_for_various_k) without any mention of how to create interpolation matrices for larger $k$. So, going by the examples provided on the page, I derived a simple algorithm to create similar matrices. While evaluating the determinants of the matrices I generated, (as these matrices must be nonsingular,) I noticed that, for a given $n$, the determinant of the corresponding $n\times n$ matrix is equal to the $(n-2)$th [superfactorial](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superfactorial.html)! So, my question is this: given the following matrix $M$:
$$
M = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
 a_{1,0} & a_{1,1} & \cdots & a_{1,n-2} & a_{1,n-1} \\
 \vdots  & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 a_{n-2,0} & a_{n-2,1} & \cdots & a_{n-2,n-2} & a_{n-2,n-1} \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
where $a_{i,j} = ((-1)^{i+1} \lceil \frac{i}{2}\rceil)^j$, does $|M| = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{n-2}k!$ hold for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $n>2$?

An example of such a matrix can be seen below:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 1  & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 & 4 & 8 & 16 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: That looks very much like a Vandermonde determinant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the are only one nonzero element in both the first and the last line our determinant is equal determinat of matrix:
$$
M' = \begin{pmatrix}
 a_{1,1} & \cdots & a_{1,n-2}  \\
 \vdots  & \ddots & \vdots \\
 a_{n-2,1} & \cdots & a_{n-2,n-2} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

For every $i$ element $a_{i,j}$ if the $j$-st degree of the first element of $i$-st line, so $M'$ is [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) multiplied by first column's elements, so
$$|M'|=\prod_{i=1}^{n-2} |a_{i,1}| \prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n-2} |a_{i,1}-a_{j,1}|.$$

For $n>3$ we have a recurrence relation $$|M'(n)|=|M'(n-1)||a_{n-2,1}|\prod_{i=1}^{n-3} |a_{i,1}-a_{n-2,1}|=$$
$$=|M'(n-1)|*\lceil \frac{n-2}{2}\rceil*(n-2)*1*(n-3)*2*\dots*\lceil \frac{n}{2}\rceil*\lceil \frac{n-4}{2}\rceil=$$
$$=|M'(n-1)|*(n-2)!,$$
that's just what we need.

Comment: Do you have a proof or a link to a proof of your first statement? It's not obvious to me that we can eliminate the first and last rows and columns. I believe it's true, but I fail to see why.

Comment: You could find it here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Vandermonde_Determinant, for example

Comment: Ah, this https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_with_Unit_Element_in_Otherwise_Zero_Row is what I was looking for, which was helpfully linked in the page you linked. Thank you.